# Combinatorial prime puzzle

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

Is it true that no prime larger than $241$ can be made by either acting or subtracting $2$ coprime numbers made up out of the prime factors $2,3,$ and $5?$

## Update

Above example is clearly wrong, as shown by MJD. New question:Is it true that $251$ cannot be made by either acting or subtracting $2$ coprime numbers made up out of the prime factors $2,3,$ and $5?$

Comment: Is $1$ allowed as one of the coprime numbers?

Comment: @MarkBennet No ;)

Comment: What is the basis for your claim?

Comment: $251 = 256 -5 = 8 +243 $.

Comment: @MJD ok - I hold my hands up & say that I certainly deserve the imminent flood of downvotes :/

Comment: @martin Please consider my computer programming suggestion. It takes only a few hours to learn how program the computer well enough to have it check this kind of conjecture, a few minutes to write the program once you know how, and a few seconds to actually run the program.

Comment: @MJD surprisingly, this question was as a result of a mistake in my programming a far more complex problem than need be for this type of question :/

Comment: @MJD I might repoost - since I have just found the source of teh problem. As far as I can see, $251$ cannot be made by adding or subtracting 2 coprimes by using *ALL* of the prime factors $2,3,5$ ... thought I might just run it by you first though!

Comment: As far as I can tell that is true.

Comment: @MJD I think it is a case of not seeing the wood for the trees :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean like $162 + 625 = 787$?

Intuitively, it would very surprising if this conjecture were true. There is no reason to expect that the sum or difference of two arbitrary numbers would not in general be prime, and there are quite a lot of primes, so something surprising would have to happen for this large family of sums and differences to almost completely miss all the primes.

Brute-force computer search finds *many* counterexamples; for example $2^{19} + 3^4  =524369$.  If you are interested in this kind of conjecture, learning a minimal amount of computer programming would be a good investment of your time.

Comment: Yes, I posted the question in haste, I am afraid. However, there certainly appears to be a list of primes greater than 241 that cannot be made.

Comment: Also $1039, 2063, 4111, 32783, 65551$ of the form $2^n+15$

Comment: @martin It's not surprising; the set of numbers that are sums or differences of 5-smooth numbers has asymptotic density 0, so one should expect its intersection with the primes to be 'small'.  But there's no reason to expect it to be finite.

Comment: (A minor correction to my previous comment: the set of sums of 5-smooth numbers has density 0, but I doubt it's known whether the set of differences of 5-smooth numbers does.  But I _believe_ that this would follow from the ABC conjecture, so it's fairly plausible.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki thanks for the note - I feel slightly embarrased that I didn't check this properly, and I shall take more time in formulating another question in a similar vain!

Comment: @martin The details on this question are off, but the topic itself is an interesting one and I encourage you to continue looking into it (though I'll warn that you're going to run into a _lot_ of 'nobody knows'!).  You might be interested in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44163/are-there-infinitely-many-primes-next-to-smooth-numbers as a question in a similar vein...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki great - thanks! (*vein!!*)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki If you have time, I would be grateful to have your thoughts on the reframed question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000060/combinatorial-prime-problem)